# OpenStack-Packstack - mariadb error

Tags: mysql, openstack, centos7

I had installed packstack, checked answer list, and tried to start OpenStack. After that it gave this error

> ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: X.X.X.X_mariadb.pp Error: Could not prefetch mysql_user provider 'mysql': Execution of '/usr/bin/mysql -NBe SELECT CONCAT(User, '@',Host) AS User FROM mysql.user' returned 1: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I changed password in answer list, changed in database(mysql_secure_installation an so on), eve tried to remove mariadb - it doesn't want to work. Have you got any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: Please visit this page before asking unclear questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask